# Opamp BJT mixed circuit analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, bjt

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have attached the problem together with the solution I have with me. I am facing problem deciding status of 2 BJT's. Please give me a generalised approach to tackle such problems.

Comment: There is no generalized approach. Proper understanding of KVL and ohms law is enough to solve all these transistor circuits.

Comment: Note that the upper schematic does not match the lower. If you are using the upper schematic, it's not wonder you have problems - that circuit will not produce a useful output. Ignore it and concentrate on the schematic shown in the answer section.

Comment: How is this different from [the question you asked 12 hours earlier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/343350/6334)? If you want to change your question, you should edit the original question (click "edit" below the question text), not re-post the same question with new wording.

Comment: Sorry for that @The Photon. I am new here. I will not repeat this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematic of the problem **does not match** the schematic of the solution. I am not sure there is a general approach to such situations.

Anyway, start off by assuming the op-amps are in balance and the transistors in active mode. That means the inverting and non-inverting inputs are at the same potential and the transistors have Vbe of about 0.7V and Vce > Vce(sat). Ignore base currents in most cases, especially if the problem does not give you hFE, since you will have no way to calculate them in the latter case.

Then try to solve the equations with the tools you know- series/parallel combination of resistances, KCL, KVL.

They ask about an edge case, from the function of creating a constant current at the output we can see that the effect of increasing the value of RL is to decrease Vce of Q2. When Vce of Q2 is equal to Vce(sat), RL can no longer be increased without greatly changing the current- so you can solve for the value of RL when Vce is exactly equal to Vce(sat). That's the 2nd part of the problem.

Comment: Actually.. the closer I look they both are...

Comment: Thanks @Spehro Sir. I got it. I am really curious to know how you were able to spot the error in schematic and if you can explain the changes you made in the schematic.

Comment: @user3653788 Lots of experience. I moved the 1.8K connection because it made no sense at all that way.